# How can I get the repeat alarm for every day using alarm manager in Android?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am developing alarm application for that I need to invoke alarm repeatedly for the same time for all days. I am using the code to invoke the alarm,

```
c = Calendar.getInstance();

    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,10);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MyAlarmService.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(HomeActivity.this, 123123, intent, 0);
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), (24*60*60*1000), pendingIntent);
```

By using this code I am only invoking present day at 10AM, not for all days. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Update time, and ring the alarm for every 5 minutes:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, this.getClass());
   PendingIntent pendingIntent =
       PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

   long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
   long nextUpdateTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis + 5 * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
   Time nextUpdateTime = new Time();
   nextUpdateTime.set(nextUpdateTimeMillis);

   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, nextUpdateTimeMillis, pendingIntent);
   ```
2. Set when the alarm works for everyday (for example, 8am-18pm)

   ```
   // if not the time to ring, set to the next day
   if (nextUpdateTime.hour < 8 || nextUpdateTime.hour >= 18)
   {
       nextUpdateTime.hour = 8;
       nextUpdateTime.minute = 0;
       nextUpdateTime.second = 0;
       nextUpdateTimeMillis = nextUpdateTime.toMillis(false) + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
   }
   else{
       // call your alarm
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your class `MyAlarmService`, when the alarm is on, reset the alarm. You can even send values for `MyAlarmService` in the intent when setting the alarm (maybe to stop the alarm)